# Python split text file into different text files when line starts with a specific character

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following txt file which is generated by an instrument:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/01rx9fk5e64y4b1/Test.txt?dl=0

Every time I run an experiment the software of the instrument appended a header which starts with "//" followed by the acquired data to the same txt file. Therefore the txt file above contains many different experiments which are separated by the header. I need to divide the file above into different txt files each one containing only one experiment and including the header.

Would the best strategy be to read line by line the file and generate a new txt file every time the programme encounters the first line that starts with "//"?
Maybe there is a better way using Pandas?
Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.*

I examined your file and it seems every header is preceded by empty line, thefore I propose exploiting that fact following way

```
fileno = 0
inputfile = open('Test.txt', 'r')
outfile = open(f'out{fileno}.txt', 'w')
for line in inputfile:
    if not line.strip():
        fileno += 1
        outfile.close()
        outfile = open(f'out{fileno}.txt', 'w')
    else:
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()
inputfile.close()
```

Explanation: process line-by-line so there is not need to load whole file to memory, if empty line encountered close current outfile and prepare new outfile with next number. Disclaimer: I used so-called f-strings so Python 3.6 or newer is required.

Comment: Hi Daweo, thank you so much for your clever suggestion and prompt reply. That's exactly what I needed.
When I try your code it gives me the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 895: invalid start byte`. I just modified line 2 like this: `inputfile = open('Test.txt', 'r', encoding='gbk')` and is working fine